# Why is there multiple collision calls Sprite Kit Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, collision

I am building an iOS swift game with collision. The hero is being bombarded by small stars coming from the right side of the screen. Every time a star hits the hero, the score is iterated and the star is removed. But, more than one point is added to the score.

**Node Set-up:**

```
var star = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "star")
star.size = CGSizeMake(30, 30)
star.zPosition = 10
var starPhysicsRect = CGRectMake(star.position.x - star.frame.size.width / 2, star.position.y - star.frame.size.width / 2, star.frame.size.width, star.frame.size.height)
star.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: starPhysicsRect)
star.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
star.name = "star"
star.physicsBody?.mass = 0
return star
```

**didBeginContact Function:**

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    //collision variables
    var firstBodyNode = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode
    var secondBodyNode = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode
    var firstNodeName = firstBodyNode.name
    var secondNodeName = secondBodyNode.name

    //other variables
    var scoreLabel: SKLabelNode = constantsInstance.scoreLabel(position: CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.86, self.frame.size.height * 0.928))


    //check if hero hit star
    if firstNodeName == "hero" && secondNodeName == "star" {
        println("star hit")
        secondBodyNode.removeFromParent()

        //iterate score
        childNodeWithName("scoreLabel")?.removeFromParent()
        scoreLabel.text = "\(counterForScore)"
        counterForScore++
        self.addChild(scoreLabel)
    }
}
```

I get "star hit" printed to the console several times as well. Why would the `didBeginContact` function be called more than once if I remove the star on the first call of the function?

I have run simulations on a smaller scale and found that the star goes fairly deep into the hero (because of the SKAction), if there is no remove command. Could it be that the `didBeginContact` function is called many times while the star is going into the hero and before it is removed?

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please show us the code where you set up your spriteNodes?

Comment: Just added the setup

Comment: Thanks! Seems there are something amiss here? `star.name = "bottomStar"` yet triggers when you check `secondName == "star"` ? Are you perhaps looking at a different interaction alltogether?

Comment: Good catch. I missed that when I was adapting my code. Sorry for the sloppy error. Just changed it back.

Comment: OK, a couple of other questions: any changes made to the sprite elsewhere? Are you just creating a single instance of the starSprite?

Comment: I declare it, just like it is shown, in a function. Then, in a separate .swift file, I assign the function's return value to a variable and add it to a parent (the SKAction that moves the stars left is run on the parent). Thanks sticking with me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89121/discussion-between-nickfalk-and-michael-berk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it possibly be due to the physicsBody:

```
var star = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "star")
star.size = CGSizeMake(30, 30)
star.zPosition = 10
var starPhysicsRect = CGRectMake(star.position.x - star.frame.size.width / 2, star.position.y - star.frame.size.width / 2, star.frame.size.width, star.frame.size.height)
star.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: starPhysicsRect)
```

Have a look at the logic creating the starPhysicsRect:

```
(star.position.x - star.frame.size.width / 2, star.position.y - star.frame.size.width / 2, star.frame.size.width, star.frame.size.height)
```

From what I can see this translates to the following values:
(-15, -15, 30, 30) those negative position-coordinates seem odd. Are you sure you don't just want: `SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: star.size)` ?

Comment: Yup. I created a box that would outline the star. But, according to this solution, creating a `CGRect` doesn't do the same job as using a `rectangleOfSize`, even if they have the same dimensions. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You can check if parent of the `SKSpriteNode` is nil before continuing.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBodyNode : SKSpriteNode!
    var secondBodyNode : SKSpriteNode!

    //  Assuming that the contact test bit mask of star is greater than hero. If it's not you should reverse the condition.

    if contact.bodyA.contactTestBitMask < contact.bodyB.contactTestBitMask {
        firstBodyNode = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode
        secondBodyNode = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode
    } else {
        firstBodyNode = contact.bodyB.node as! SKSpriteNode
        secondBodyNode = contact.bodyA.node as! SKSpriteNode
    }

    var firstNodeName = firstBodyNode.name
    var secondNodeName = secondBodyNode.name

    if firstNodeName == "hero" && secondNodeName == "star" {
        if secondBodyNode.parent != nil {
           // Your code.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried that and I still have the problem. What were you trying to accomplish by checking for nil?

Comment: removeFromParent would cause the parent of the star to be `nil`.

Comment: did you check if parent is `nil` after changing the 'bottomStar' part?

Comment: Yup. Can I give you guys more useful information? Thanks again for the help.