# Swift SpriteKit Collisions Registered Multiple Times

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skphysicsbody

I'm using SpriteKit and Swift to build an iPhone game, and my collision detection system is not functioning as I want it to. When my "bullet" physics body and my "player" physics body collide, the collision detection function is being called multiple times, usually 4-12 times. I have tried setting "usesPreciseCollisionDetection" to true, but it is still problematic. Also, it seems the method is called more times when the bullet hits the player at an angle rather than straight on. Any thoughts how to fix this?

Collision Types:

```
enum ColliderType:UInt32 {
    case Player = 0b1
    case Bullet = 0b10
}
```

Player Physics Body Settings:

```
playerBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Player.rawValue
playerBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Bullet.rawValue
playerBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Bullet.rawValue
```

Bullet Physics Body Settings:

```
bulletBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Bullet.rawValue
bulletBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Player.rawValue
bulletBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Player.rawValue
```

Collision Detection Method:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == 0b1) && (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == 0b10) {
        playerVbullet(contact.bodyA, bullet: contact.bodyB)
    }

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == 0b10) && (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == 0b11) {
        playerVbullet(contact.bodyB, bullet: contact.bodyA)
    }
}
```

Function Called on Collision:

```
func playerVbullet(player:SKPhysicsBody, bullet:SKPhysicsBody) {
    bullet.node?.removeFromParent()
    collisions++
    println(collisions)
}
```

Comment: removing from parent does not remove the existence of the object,  the object will exist until all references are gone.  also, your collision code is wrong I am guessing, `contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == 0b11 can't be accurate`,  it has 2 flag markings

Comment: Can we see how you defined the SKPhysicsBody playerBody and bulletBody too? Do you have any lines like these?
physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()
physicsBody!.dynamic = true

Comment: I like to do my bitmasks like this, so it's less confusing:
let FieldBitMask: UInt32 =       00000000000000000000000000000001
physicsBody!.fieldBitMask = FieldBitMask

Comment: Each digit represents the 16 categories that you can have for collisions, physics fields, and categories.

Comment: I fixed the 0b11 error, it's not the problem. KnightOfDragon, what do you mean by removing all references? How can I delete the object entirely?

Comment: jmcmahon443, here is my code for defining the bodies:

Comment: bulletBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "bullet"), size: CGSize(width: bullet.size.width, height: bullet.size.height));                        
bullet.physicsBody = bulletBody;                                
let playerBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "stand"), size: CGSize(width: player.size.width, height: player.size.height));                         
player.physicsBody = playerBody;

Comment: @JFisher How do you move your nodes ? Do you use applyImpulse and applyForce methods or something else ?

Comment: @JFisher Also, you don't need a collisions between player and a bullet (you obviously need just contact detection), because it can be seen from your code that you are removing a bullet right after a contact is made. So set bullet.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0 and player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0. Of course, you can set player's collisionBitMask appropriately for other bodies like walls, platforms etc... And you can try this solution (posted by rakeshbs) : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32470600/3402095

Comment: @JFisher I mean the bullet still exists until nothing calls it anymore.  Since the node is being passed into didBeginContact,  something above (in the API) is holding a reference to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your bullet node a name:

```
let bullet = SKSPriteNode()
bullet.name = "bullet"
```

Then check your physics contact

```
if (contact.bodyA.node?.name == "bullet") {
    contact.bodyA.node?.removeFromParent()
} else if contact.bodyB.node?.name == "bullet" {
    contact.bodyB.node?.removeFromParent()
}
```

Good luck!